# laravel route name parameter

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Use a pageNation to request the value of the page to the controller. But why can't any parameters reach the controller?

```
 Route::get('/index', 'Penpal\ViewController@index')->name('penpal.index');

 <form action="{!! route('penpal.index', ['menu' => 'p11-c3']) !!}" method="get">
            <select id="inputState" class="form-control" style="height:35px; width:80%" name="pagination" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                    <option value="3">@lang('penpal/component/indexMenu.twelve')</option>
                    <option value="4">@lang('penpal/component/indexMenu.twenty_four')</option>
                    <option value="5">@lang('penpal/component/indexMenu.thirty_six')</option>
                </select>
        </form>    


 public function index (Request $request){
    return $request;\
 }
```

A parameter named "menu" cannot be received from the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Use Post method both route and form

<form action="{!! route('penpal.index', ['menu' => 'p11-c3']) !!}" method="post">
Route::match(['get','post'],'/index', 'Penpal\ViewController@index')->name('penpal.index');
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 3):

Your `<form>` is using `method='get'`, instead of `method='POST'` (which is used to post data to the request via a form.

You will also need to use `@csrf` in your blade template or you will not be able to post data:

```
<form action="{!! route('penpal.index', ['menu' => 'p11-c3']) !!}" method="POST">
   @csrf
   <select id="inputState" class="form-control" style="height:35px; width:80%" name="pagination" onchange="this.form.submit()">
      <option value="3">@lang('penpal/component/indexMenu.twelve')</option>
      <option value="4">@lang('penpal/component/indexMenu.twenty_four')</option>
      <option value="5">@lang('penpal/component/indexMenu.thirty_six')</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

Finally, make sure that your route is a `::post()` route.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set any route parameters for your route and neither passing any to your controller method. And it would be a better idea to use POST then GET.

Change this to

```
Route::get('/index', 'Penpal\ViewController@index')->name('penpal.index');
```

this

```
Route::post('/index/{menu?}', 'Penpal\ViewController@index')->name('penpal.index');
```

and your form

```
<form action="{{ route('penpal.index', ['menu' => 'p11-c3']) }}" method="POST">
@csrf
```

And in your controller method you can fetch the passed parameter

```
 public function index (Request $request, $menu){
    print_r($menu);
 }
```